# Getter for an Object in a ArrayList

Tags: java, object, arraylist, getter

I have an object in an ArrayList and I want to print the object on my screen but I can't do it with those getters. How can I do this?

```
public void start() {
            ArrayList rij = new ArrayList();
            rij.add(new Persoon("Foo","Bar",18));
            rij.add(new Persoon("Jane","Doe",52));
            rij.add(new Persoon("John","Doe",23));

            for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
                System.out.println((Persoon)rij.get(i).getNaam() + " " + rij.get(i).getVoornaam() + " " + rij.get(i).getLeeftijd());
            }
        }



    private String naam = "";
        private String voornaam = "";
        private int leeftijd = 0;

        public Persoon(String naam, String voornaam, int leeftijd){
            this.naam = naam;
            this.voornaam = voornaam;
            this.leeftijd = leeftijd;
        }

        public String getNaam(){
             return naam;
        }

        public String getVoornaam(){
            return voornaam;
        }

        public int getLeeftijd(){
            return leeftijd;
        }
```

Comment: Why not just write your own `toString` method for your object?

Comment: Declare arraylist as List<Persoon> rij=new ArrayList<Persoon>();

Comment: Use generics, or add parentheses.

Comment: Also, you misspelled `Person`.

Comment: I don't want the whole object. Just the first part or something with those getters.

Comment: @Gianni, can you confirm that you're getting a ClassCastException?

Comment: @SLaks English doesn't appear to be his first language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is your cast to `Persoon` is being applied to `rij.get(i).getNaam()`, not to `rij.get(i)`.

What you want is:

`((Persoon)rij.get(i)).getNaam()` etc

Or more simply:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    Persoon p = rij.get(i);
    System.out.println(p.getNaam() + " " + p.getVoornaam() + " " + p.getLeeftijd());
}
```

The parentheses matter. You have know exactly what you're casting and when.

Comment: Thank you very much!
I'm new into java, so this helps me a lot!

Comment: But what you should really do is use generics instead of using the raw type `ArrayList`; see JB Nizet's answer. Then you wouldn't need the cast at all.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a raw ArrayList. Use a generic one:

This will ensure type-safety, and allow you to avoid casts completely.

```
List<Persoon> personen = new ArrayList<Persoon>();
//...

for (int i = 0; i < personen.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(personen.get(i).getNaam() + " " + personen.get(i).getVoornaam() + " " + personen.get(i).getLeeftijd());
}
```

Using the foreach loop will also lead to safer and more readable code:

```
List<Persoon> personen = new ArrayList<Persoon>();
//...

for (Persoon persoon : personen) {
    System.out.println(persoon.getNaam() + " " + persoon.getVoornaam() + " " + persoon.getLeeftijd());
}
```

Comment: The plural of 'persoon' is 'personen' in Dutch... ;-)

Comment: @Jesper: given that I'm Belgian and learnt Dutch whan I was at school, I feel obligated to fix my answer :-) But I hate code in any non-English language, even French (which is my mother tongue)

Comment: @Gianni: Ouch. Then you have an incompetent teacher, that hasn't learnt anything new regarding Java for many many years (2004). Unless they intentionally teach you bad practices to teach you the good ones after, which I would personally also find stupid.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print `Person` object, Try this and Override `toString()` method in your `Person` class

```
System.out.println((Persoon)rij.get(i));
```

Comment: He will need to override the `toString` method, otherwise the output will be pretty useless to him.

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend in the case you are storing obect like "People" in your case.Its always better to use "iterator"

```
 ArrayList rij = new ArrayList();
        rij.add(new Persoon("Foo","Bar",18));
        rij.add(new Persoon("Jane","Doe",52));
        rij.add(new Persoon("John","Doe",23));
        Iterator item=rij.iterator();
        while (item.hasNext()){
            Persoon person=(Persoon)item.next();
            System.out.println(person.getNaam() + " " + person.getVoornaam() + " " + person.getLeeftijd());
        }
```

> **java.util.iterator;**

hope it ll work.If not tell me i ll forward the complete code.. :D